# Checking the status of Apify during the execution of any process

Tags: node.js, express, apify

Let's assume a server

```
const Apify = require("apify");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/run", async (_, res) => {
  Apify.main(async () => {
    // Let the actor run for an hour.
    await Apify.utils.sleep(60 * 60 * 1000);
  });
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/state", async (req, res) => {
  const pageHtml = `

<html>
    <head><title>Example</title></head>
    <body>
       <pre>${JSON.stringify(Apify.utils.log)}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
`;
  res.send(pageHtml);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Application is listening at URL ${APIFY_CONTAINER_URL}.`);
});
```

It doesn't do anything except `express` and `apify` working.

How can I catch the state of `Apify`?

I need to know

- is there a working actor now?
- is there a sleep state?
- what is main state of Apify now?

No Apify Cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to wrap all your code inside Apify.main:

```js
const Apify = require("apify");
const express = require("express");

Apify.main(async () => {
    const app = express();

    app.get("/run", async (_, res) => {
      res.redirect("/");
    });
    
    app.get("/state", async (req, res) => {
      const pageHtml = `
    
    <html>
        <head><title>Example</title></head>
        <body>
           <pre>${JSON.stringify(Apify.utils.log)}</pre>
        </body>
    </html>
    `;
      res.send(pageHtml);
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log(`Application is listening at URL ${APIFY_CONTAINER_URL}.`);
    });
    
    await new Promise(() => {}); // wait forever    
});
```

you can use the bare minimum example here for future reference https://github.com/metalwarrior665/apify-utils/blob/master/examples/express-server.js